# .htaccess file is not read in linux

Tags: php, linux, .htaccess, ubuntu, apache2

I have a .htaccess file in a php project, I have the apache2 server downloaded and running, but it ignores my project's .htaccess.

When I test the project on Windows or put it on my hosting it works normally.

I already tried to edit the apache2.conf file, among several other methods that I found to solve, and nothing worked, the project worked correctly on the computer of my friends who have linux.

I start the project with the command `php -S localhost: 1990` inside the folder that has my files, I tried other ways and nothing worked.
Can someone help me? I've been looking for a long time and nothing has resolved.

I apologize for my English, I'm Brazilian and I still can't speak English very well.

Comment: Did you restart Apache after editing config files?

Answer (score 0):

> I start the project with the command `php -S localhost: 1990`

This uses the webserver built-in to PHP, not Apache. Consequently, this does not use a `.htaccess` file (or `apache2.conf`).

You need to call your PHP files through Apache - which you say is already "running". (?)

(*Aside:* There should be no space between `localhost:` and `1990`.)

Reference:

- https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php